AttributeError: module 'apex.amp' has no attribute 'state_dict'
checkpoint['amp'] = apex.amp.state_dict()
AttributeError: module 'apex.amp' has no attribute 'state_dict'

torch              1.10.0+cu111
torchaudio         0.10.0+rocm4.1
torchvision        0.11.0+cu111

After using apex.amp.state_dict(), whenever I am trying to run, this error is coming. I could not able to find any solution for this. though I read about this that create another environment and this error will be solved but did not work for me. Please find the details of my system. for reference, I am using Python 3.7.16. I could not find any similar question online or any other solutions. I tried to install from GitHub, but it did not work.
